# Django multiplechoicefield always renders None

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I made a multiplechoicefield form (to ask what category user wants to select), but i can't get the answer back...it always renders "None".
I added some 'print' in the code to be sure that it was the problem and it is.
I don't understand why.

forms.py:

```
class Category(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Auctions
        fields = ("category",)
        #fields = ('category',)
        #widgets = {'category' : forms.RadioSelect()}
        catform = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=fields, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

models.py
'''
class Auctions(models.Model):

```
Category = [('FASHION', 'Fashion'),('TOYS','Toys'),('ELECTRONICS','Electronics'),('HOME','Home')]

ID_auction = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
title = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
description = models.TextField()
startingbid = models.IntegerField()
image = models.URLField(blank = True)
category = models.CharField(max_length = 80, choices = Category)
author_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "auteur")
highest_bid = models.IntegerField("Bid", blank = True, null = True)
buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "acheteur")
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

'''

views.py
'''

```
def filter_cat(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Category(request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            cat = form.cleaned_data.get("catform")
            print(cat)
            auctions = Auctions.objects.filter(category = cat)
            return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
                'active_listing' : auctions, 'cat' : cat
                })
    else :
        form = Category()
        return render(request, "auctions/filter_cat.html",{'form' : form})
```

'''

when I select FASHION for example i get this on the terminal :

for print(form):

Category:
  ---------
  Fashion
  Toys
  Electronics
  Home

for print(cat):

None

Comment: `catform` is defined in `Meta` and so is not a valid field, `form.cleaned_data.get("catform")` will always return `None` because there will never be data for a field that doesn't exist. Do you mean to be accessing the `category` field?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to take a look. Yes that's what i try to do, I want the user to select a category and then use it to filter.

Comment: Thank's to your help I found the problem. I saw on the internet this use of "forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=fields, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())". I just deleted it and it solved the problem. Thank's again!